# Ajax and checkbox array

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Im just new in using ajax and I was following a tutorial from this link http://ricochen.wordpress.com/2011/08/02/passing-array-of-checkbox-values-to-php-through-jquery-example/
But i wasnt able to make it work can you pls help me on this?

html code :

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script> 
 <script type="text/javascript">
                function doit() {
                        var p=[];
                        $('input.cb').each( function() {
                                if($(this).attr('checked')) {
                                        p.push($(this).attr('rel'));
                                }
                        } );
                        $.ajax( {
                                url:'/test2.php',
                                type:'POST',
                                data: {list:p},
                                success: function(res) {
                                        alert(res);
                                }
                        });
                }
        </script>
</head>
<body>       
 <input type="checkbox" class="cb" rel="1"></input>This is 1<br />
        <input type="checkbox" class="cb" rel="abc"></input>This is abc<br />
        <input type="checkbox" class="cb" rel="999"></input>This is 999<br />
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="doit()">Click</a>       
</body>
</html>
```

test2.php :

```
<?php

        print_r(@$_POST['list']);

?>
```

Comment: And what exactly isn't working ?

Comment: try to alert something just after the  function doit() {  and check whether it is alerting..

Comment: @jenz i tried using this and replace the onClick function and it worked function qwe()
    {
    alert('test');
    }

Comment: @jenz what i need is to pass array checkbox so i saw this tutorial and try it but it doesnt work

Comment: check whether the data is passed to test2.php by echoing some text inside that file..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:
1:you use `<input></input>` this is wrong!!! `<input type='checkbox' name='' />`
2:you each all `checkbox` you can each `$('input.cb:checked')` and remove `if`
3:you want post ajax so use `$.post`

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script> 
 <script type="text/javascript">
                function doit() {
                        var p=[];
                        $('input.cb:checked').each(function(index,value) {                                
                                        p.push($(value).attr('rel'));
                        });
                        $.post('/test2.php',{list:p}).done(function(res) {alert(res);});
                }
        </script>
</head>
<body>       
        <input type="checkbox" class="cb" rel="1"/>This is 1<br />
        <input type="checkbox" class="cb" rel="abc"/>This is abc<br />
        <input type="checkbox" class="cb" rel="999"/>This is 999<br />
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="doit()">Click</a>       
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i tried using this and remove this part $.post('/test2.php',{list:p}).done(function(res) there was no alert showing

Comment: because this is not `done` may not found your php file,i test it and give alert `Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => abc
)` your php file must beside your html file in <b>web server</b> if not work change file address and remove `/` before test2.php

Comment: ok you saved my day !!!!! if i can check this as an aswer three times i would tnx!

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
$('input.cb').each( function() {
       if($(this).is(':checked')) { // change this line in your code
            p.push($(this).attr('rel'));
       }
 });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DV6JA/9/)

Comment: OK i love you! finally it works! can you help me further on my goal if its ok?

Comment: @zxc yes tell me `:-)`

Comment: tnx! uhm i need to pass the array checkbox to the test2.php what i did in the test2.php is $list=$_POST['list']; im having a problem on the ajax post part

Comment: uhm theres no error showing but theres no data getting inserted in the db. what i did is get the POST[LIST] then insert it into db.

Comment: is  `print_r(@$_POST['list']);` or echo display the checkbox value or not?

Comment: `<?php 
$list = isset($_POST['list'])? $_POST['list'] : '';  
echo $list; 
?> `

Answer (score 0):

using onclick="" attribut is kind of deprecated + you should'nt use a link for an action you should use a button. link are for pages and button for action.
http://jsfiddle.net/tLq8L/1/ <-- check it here for a working version

```
 <script>
 function doit() {

                    var p=[];
                    $('input.cb').each( function() {
                            if($(this).attr('checked')) {
                                    p.push($(this).attr('rel'));
                            }
                    } );
                    $.ajax( {
                            url:'/test2.php',
                            type:'POST',
                            data: {list:p},
                            success: function(res) {
                                    alert(res);
                            }
                    });
            }
 </script>
  <input type="checkbox" class="cb" rel="1"></input>This is 1<br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" rel="abc"></input>This is abc<br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" rel="999"></input>This is 999<br />
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="doit()">Click</a>
```

Comment: it's working check with a tool like httpfox or chrome developper to see the http request for course it's ending in error cause I don't have your test2.php

Answer (score 0):

`if($(this).prop('checked'))` instead of `if($(this).attr('checked'))` will solve your problem